# There is no argument given that corresponds to the required parmeter

Tags: c#, parameters, arguments

I have no idea what is wrong..

```
    public static void OnSpam(Client client)
    {
        PlayerTextPacket pkt = (PlayerTextPacket)Packet.Create(PacketType.PLAYERTEXT);
        pkt.Text = "Test";
        client.SendToServer(pkt);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1.OnSpam();
    }
```

under Form1.OnSpam(); it says "There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'client' of 'Form1.OnSpam(Client)'" any idea of what to do?

Answer (score 3):

It's pretty clear.  Your `OnSpam` method takes an argument:

```
public static void OnSpam(Client client) //<-- see the argument?
```

And you're calling it without the argument:

```
Form1.OnSpam(); //<-- see no argument?
```

Somehow, you need to get an instance of `Client` and pass it to that method call.

Comment: When i try adding Client to: private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) it says "No overload for 'button1_Click' matches delegate 'EventHandler'

Comment: You need to get it elsewhere.  Where are you getting your client?

Comment: Okay, so where are you getting the instance of `Client` from?  Are you instantiating it yourself?

Comment: It says its from metadata.. All I know is that I got it because I added a reference

Comment: Then I'm sorry, I don't know how else to help you.  This is basic stuff.  You can't call a method that takes an argument without providing an instance of that argument's type.

Comment: Well I use Client elsewhere in the solution for example http://prntscr.com/983f3i

Comment: what happens when you step through the code setting break points..?

Comment: @MethodMan -- He can't step through the code obviously.  It's a compiler error.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `Form1.OnSpam(button1.CommandParameter as Client)`. This parameter is accepted by visual studio. You have to pass object of type Client to call the `OnSpam` method. You can try other objects from intellisence and cast them as Client type.